# Solr Content Update Issue

Tags: solr

We use a Solr 6.6.1 server with basic settings and an own plugin that modifies texts. We commit the incoming data changes after 5 minutes and we run an optimisation every week. The data size is 700 MB and currently 512 MB memory is used for Solr (default settings).

We got a notification from a user that the effects of some data changes aren’t displayed. However, in Solr log we see that the data change has been received:

> 2018-12-06 11:23:05.017 INFO (qtp1205044462-128704) [ x:gs] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [gs] webapp=/solr path=/update params={}{add=[1923049 (1619101362438537216)]} 0 1

If we request the document directly in Solr it appears with the changed data in the search results, otherwise only the unchanged data is shown.

It is a rare issue, we can’t reproduce it, and the other data changes of the same user are also displayed correctly. The site is used by hundreds of users, no similar issue was reported.

Is it possible that some cache value is not removed during the commit?
Do you have any idea what could cause this kind of problem?

Comment: So when does the actual commit happen? Could it be that multiple updates happen, overwriting the previous one with stale content?

Comment: Commit happens every 5 minutes. After that, when we check the item it shows the updated content, but for some reason the search is working with the previous content.

Comment: If you only have a single server (and we can exclude any issues related to replication), this is usually caused by older searchers being kept open and not being replaced with a new one. Are you committing anything with `openSearcher="false"` or any similar settings? Do you get any errors in the log about issues with opening a new searcher at any time?

Comment: And are these issues also present if you use Solr's UI to query directly into Solr? (to keep any caches inside your application out of the mix)

Comment: Thanks, we will look into the opensearcher issue. We don't use autocommit, but we run commit from command line.